# What are the assumptions of linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Can anyone explain the **assumptions of linear regressions**?

If possible with an example?

Is this really important to check these assumptions before proceeding?

Comment: There are some but one of them which is really important is iid and you can't believe the importance of that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the links I have found:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions

https://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-linear-regression/

http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html